# Has there been a recent change in the airspace configuration at KFYV-- Drake Field near Fayetteville AR?

Tags: airspace, aeronautical-charts, class-e-airspace

Has there been a recent change in the airspace configuration at KFYV-- Drake Field near Fayetteville AR?  If so, where can we find an official description of that change?

KFYV -- Drake Field airport at Fayetteville Arkansas http://vfrmap.com/?type=vfrc&lat=36.005&lon=-94.170&zoom=10

(Memphis sectional chart, western portion of north half)

A sectional chart dated April 13 2006 shows a class D circle with a large E4 (dashed magenta) extension to the south, but on the current sectional chart (effective March 28 2019) the area projecting to the south is now much smaller and is class D rather than E4.

Has there been a recent change in the airspace here?

If so, what is the official FAA source that describes that change?

I do not see the airspace configuration as shown on the current sectional to be reflected in the August 2018 edition of the FAA's "Airspace Designations and Reporting Points" document ( https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/JO_7400.11C.pdf ) , or in the more recent amendments given here https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/airspace_amendments/

The Class D airspace is described on page D-112 of the "Airspace Designations and Reporting Points" document, and the E4 airspace is described on page E-206.  The description matches what I see on the 2006 sectional chart.

Is the current sectional chart simply wrong?

Comment: You don't have to add "answered" to the title of the question, simply mark your answer as the answer and it will show up green in searches.

Comment: Got it.  Looks like it won't let me do that for two more days though.

Comment: No problem, just mark it when you can unless something better comes along. There is no issue here with answering your own questions, it is highly encouraged even.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little more googling has provided an answer -- on 12/10/18, effective 2/28/19, the extension was greatly reduced in size (and the remaining bit converted to class D) due to the decommissioning of the Drake VHF omnidirectional range (VOR) navigation aid -- see https://www.federalregister.gov/documents/2018/12/10/2018-26498/amendment-of-class-d-and-e-airspace-and-revocation-of-class-e-airspace-fayetteville-ar

I'm not sure why that airspace change was not reflected in any of these documents-- https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/airspace_amendments/

Actually, it was there, I just didn't see it because they mistakenly used the abbreviation "AK" not "AR" for Arkansas in the table.

Nothing more need be said here--